# How to add timestamp as firebase key

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a timestamp as a custom key in firebase however I can't add it since it always gives me an error.

This is how I'm inserting into the database.

```
db.ref('items/').child(timestamp).set({
       name: item,
       type: type,
   })
```

This is how I get the timestamp:
`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

And the error I get is
Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path= "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't containt ., #, $, [ or ].

I don't understand what is going on here and if I add that same timestamp as a value of one child it adds it without and problem

Comment: You can't use Firebase's server-side timestamp as a key. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274974/how-to-use-firebases-servervalue-timestamp-as-a-child-and-set-a-value-to-it

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.ServerValue), the value you get with `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is an Object but you have to pass a String to the [`child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference.html#child) method.

This is what the error message indicates:

> Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path= "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't containt ., #, $, [ or ].

You may generate the timestamp in your front end and pass it to the `child()` method, see [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

---

In addition, note that `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is "a **placeholder value** for auto-populating the current timestamp... as determined **by the Firebase servers**" . It means that you cannot call a JavaScript method (e.g. `getTime()`) on it, in your front-end.