# Firebase Realtime Database: setting server TIMESTAMP as the key of the node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I am trying to access the time a new entry is made to the Firebase Realtime Database (when it is acctually uploaded on the server) and set it as a key to that entry. Rather simmilar question was set by one other post but with no clear answer:

[How to use Firebase's ServerValue.TIMESTAMP as a child and set a value to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274974/how-to-use-firebases-servervalue-timestamp-as-a-child-and-set-a-value-to-it)

[image]

To illustrate this: I wish to have server timestamp as the node to an entry (on this picture shown in red). I have initially tried with server timestamp: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` call did give me entry when inputed as a variable in an object ("messageUploadedTime" on the picture). However, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a `Map<String, String>` and therefore cannot be directly used as `.child(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).setValue(model)` which required a String key, making it unusable in this case.

With this in mind, I am looking for another method I could accomplish the same thing as TIMESTAMP but that would acctually work.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly you tried that didn't work the way you expect.  Please edit the question to share the code you tried, stating what it did that wasn't what you wanted.  Also please link to the other questions that don't address your concerns.  It seems that you might simply misunderstand how server timestamps work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have now edited and additionally argumented the post - I am sorry if the post before was not clear enough.

Comment: @DougStevenson you gave a very good response in the 1st link I provided, especially last paragraph. However, you did not specifically provide a method how I could do this and as I couldn't find this anywhere I have posted this question.

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from the one you linked. As Doug explained in both cases, you can't use the server-side timestamp as a key for a node in a single write operation. In his answer to both questions, Doug even describes a workaround (using Cloud Functions) on how to get the result. I'm voting to close this as a duplicate, but feel free to explain why you think your case is different and why it should be reopened.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen after talking to Doug, I finally realised that the solution to my problem is not as simple as I thought and completely different from the original question as I would require an implementaion of Cloud Functions on their server to achieve my goal. As of this, I will rather risk slower queries with orderByChild() + index opposed to orderByKey() which was the whole point of change. With this in mind, it is for the best if question stays closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in the way you're expecting.  ServerValue.TIMESTAMP can only be used as the value of a child, not the key of the child.  The special meaning it has, encoded by a Map (as you've seen), can only be understood as a child value.  On top of that, the value eventually written is a long integer type value, while all keys are always taken as string values.

The best you can do is write the value to a child value somewhere, read it back, convert it to a string, and use that to identify a new child to write.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way one can use TIMESTAMP as a key? But didn't you mention yourself in the 1st link this is somehow possible using Google Cloud functions?

Comment: Sure, you can use Cloud Functions or some other backend you control to generate a reliable timestamp, convert it to a string, and use that as a timestamp.  It will not have anything to do with ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.  It's a completely different thing.

Comment: Ohhh I see. So basically you're saying that, while I cannot use TIMESTAMP for this, there are other methods how I can set node key to a time uploaded on a server? Can you plese tell me how I can do that (you probably can edit your post with this)?

Comment: To be honest, it's a whole different question.  I suggest making an attempt with some backend of your choice, and posting again if you get stuck with your chosen implementation, explaining what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I see. Will wait a little bit as someone might assist me how to do this here. Otherwise I will just post another question as I feel this is not explained anywhere. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, I do not fully understand what do you mean with "backend of my choice". I am using firebase as my only server's backend at this point.

Comment: Whatever you choose to run code on any backend, and not on the client.  It's up to you.  Start implementing, and post again if you get stuck. Since you haven't started coding yet, your question is too broad to be answered.  Right now, your question is about ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, which I am saying is not going to work on a client app.

Comment: I will say that if you're settled on using Cloud Functions, then just start implementing your ideas now.  I don't think anyone is going to write your code for you, since your requirements are a bit vague right now.  Once you have your implementation plan in place, we can help where you get stuck.  You still have a lot of decisions to make about how to go about this.

Comment: First of all, thank you again for your help. Before posting this question, I thought that the solution is quite simple: invoke a special function that would solve the issue. However, after your comments, I realise that in order to do what I desire, I need to run code on Google Cloud Functions platform which presents an extra layer. Based on this, I belive that the easiest solution is that I just store the TIMESTAMP as one of the variables of an object an not the key. I read that orderByKey() is much faster than orderByChild() + index which was the reason I wanted this at the first place.